# Update order status after updating order shipping address using plugin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, plugin, address

I am trying to update the order status after the shipping address was changed manually from the adminpanel (when the order is already created).

This is my `di.xml` content:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository">
    <plugin name="custom_order_status" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderAddressAfterSave" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

and the `OrderAddressAfterSave` content:

```
    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;

    class OrderAddressAfterSave
    {
        public function afterSave(OrderAddressInterface $subject, $result)
        {
            return $result;

        }
    }
```

If the order status is `shipping_error` and someone updates the shipping address from adminpanel, I would like to update the order status from `shipping_error` to `processing`.

Currently I am running into this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderAddressAfterSave::afterSave() must implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface, instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository\Interceptor given, called in path/to/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in path/to/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/OrderAddressAfterSave.php:8 Stack trace: #0 path/to/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderAddressAfterSave->afterSave(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address)) #1 path/to/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Ord in /path/to/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/OrderAddressAfterSave.php on line 8
```

Any idea why? and what would be the best approach to fix this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Was getting that error because of the type name was incorrect. Instead of:
`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository` I need to change into the `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface`.